# Plone 3.2 KUPU Image Caption Impossible

Tags: plone, wysiwyg, caption

I have been having difficulty in captioning images using KUPU in Plone 3.2

I have enabled the following under the "Visual Editor" in mysite.com/plone_control_panel:

- Link using UIDs
- Allow captioned images

When browsing the KUPU "Insert Image" box, I can select an image. Enter "Text Equivalent" text and tick the "Caption" box. Once I click this box my "Text Equivalent" box disappears, but nothing else appears, thus preventing me from entering any caption text.

If I tick the "Caption" box and save my page I can see the following in my HTML:

```
<dl class="image-left captioned">
 <dt>
   <img width="400" height="299" title="PTA" alt="PTA" src="image.JPG">
 </dt>
 <dd style="width:400px" class="image-caption"></dd>
</dl>
```

As you can see, it creates the necessary HTML I am just unable to alter the text contained within the

```
 <dd style="width:400px" class="image-caption"></dd>
```

tags.

I can see no javascript errors in my Firebug console for anything related to captioning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caption-tag gets the description of of the image-item, so to change the caption you need to edit the image itself and change the description.

Note that this value is cached, so you need to clear the browsercache to see the changement on reload of the page with the inserted image.